# Port existing code first models, and fluent aPI configuration from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0

Assuming in an application utilizing Ef 6, I have the following model and fluentapi configurations that defines the relationship between a car owner and the car/cars he owns. The relationship between a Car and a CarOwner is 1 to 0 or 1, while the relationship between CarOwner and Car is 1 to 0 or many;

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChasisNumber { get; set; }
    public string EngineNumber { get; set; }

    public CarOwner CarOwner { get; set; }
}

public class CarOwner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IList<Car> Cars {get; set;}
}
```

With a corresponding fluent api configuration shown below

```
public class CarConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    HasKey(a => a.Id);
    Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
    HasOptional(x => x.CarOwner).WithMany(x => x.Cars).Map(x => x.MapKey("CarOwner_Id"));
}

public class CarOwnerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CarOwner>
{
    HasKey(a => a.Id);
    Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
    HasMany(a => a.Cars).WithOptional(a => a.CarOwner);
}
```

In EF Core 2.0 the Car model changes because of the need to specify the CarOwner foreign key in the Model as a nullable integer property but I dont want to do that.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChasisNumber { get; set; }
    public string EngineNumber { get; set; }

    public int? CarOwnerId { get;set; }
    public CarOwner CarOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can prevent adding the CarOwnerId as a reference key in the Car entity? I want to ensure my model stay same at it was in Entity Framework 6. I don't want to make any change to my model. I would prefer to make all the necessary changes in the fluent api configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In EF Core 2.0 the Car model changes because of the need to specify the CarOwner foreign key in the Model as a nullable integer property

Definitely there is no need to do that. In fact EF Core gives you much more control over the [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties). Just the default FK name convention is different, so in order to keep the EF6 names you have to explicitly configure them with fluent API.

Here is the equivalent EF Core configuration of the original model (w/o `public int? CarOwnerId { get;set; }` inside the `Car`):

```
public class CarConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Car> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);
        builder.Property(a => a.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().IsRequired();
        builder.HasOne(x => x.CarOwner)
            .WithMany(x => x.Cars)
            .HasForeignKey("CarOwner_Id") // <--
            .IsRequired(false);
    }
}

public class CarOwnerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CarOwner>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CarOwner> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);
        builder.Property(a => a.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Note that most of the fluent configurations are redundant and can be omitted since they are the EF conventional defaults. Also relationship configuration should be in one place in order to avoid conflicting setups - relationship always has 2 ends, so logically it's not a part of any of the two entities (doesn't fit well in the entity type configuration separation).

The minimal fluent configuration which achieves the same mapping is like this (not using entity type configurations at all):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
    .HasOne(x => x.CarOwner)
    .WithMany(x => x.Cars)
    .HasForeignKey("CarOwner_Id");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to answer. Your answer was very helpful